# having Keyerror in df.loc . I want to see the information related to 'mdavis@yahoo.com' using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get information on a certain entry from my data frame using .loc method. But I see an error.

```
people = {'first' : ['Rubayet','Eric','Jake','Sarah','Tilman','Yoni'],
           'last' : ['Alam','Matthes','Vanderplas','Guido','M. Davis','Nazarathy'],
           'email': ['rubayet_alam@yahoo.com', 'ericm@gmail.com', 'jvplas@gmail.com','sarah12@gmail.com', 'mdavis@yahoo.com','yoni@hotmail.com'],
     'occupation' : ['student','programmer','writer','writer','engineer','writer']}

df = pd.DataFrame(people)

df.loc['mdavis@yahoo.com']
```

this displays a `KeyError`.

Comment: `df = df.set_index('email')`

Answer (score 0):

This fails as `loc` is an accessor for the **index**.

You either need to set "email" as your index:

```
df = df.set_index('email')
df.loc['mdavis@yahoo.com']
```

or slice the value from the column:

```
df[df['email' ].eq('mdavis@yahoo.com')]
```

or use the `query` method:

```
df.query('email == "mdavis@yahoo.com")
```